# Compare and see if the user click the right radio button for android quiz answer

Tags: android

Hello guys I need to make a simple android quiz. Well what I've done so for is these with the help of other examples online.

**MyOSIActivity.java**

```
package com.mns.mp;


import tp.mns.mp.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyOSIActivity extends Activity {

    private RadioGroup radioAnswerGroup;
    private RadioButton radioAnswerButton;
    private Button btnSubmit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        radioAnswerGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioAnswer);
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // get selected radio button from radioGroup
                int selectedId = radioAnswerGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                // find the radiobutton by returned id
                radioAnswerButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

                Toast.makeText(MyOSIActivity.this,
                        radioAnswerButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });

    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Qn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/Qn_1"
       />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioAnswer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_1" 
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_2" />

         <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_3" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="hello">Hello World, MyAndroidAppActivity!</string>
    <string name="app_name">MyAndroidApp</string>
    <string name="Qn_1"> Question 1: Acknowledgement, Sequencing, and Flow control are characteristics of which OSI layer?</string>
    <string name="radio_1">Layer 2</string>
    <string name="radio_2"> Layer 3</string>
    <string name="radio_3"> Layer 4</string>
    <string name="btn_submit">Submit</string>

</resources>
```

Ok now I'm trying to make the system compare the user answer with the correct answer after the user press submit button which in this case its Layer 4. Then if the user answer is wrong, the toast will reply to the user it is incorrect and show the correct answer. Where as if the user is correct then it will reply correct to the user. So I need to use if else but the thing is I am still not familiar with it. Ill appreciate if you guys give me guidances because I really need it. Thank you soo much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this in so many ways.... if you know the id of the correct answer, you can do:

```
if (selectedId==correctId){
    //show toast saying it is correct
}
else{
    //toast incorrect
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much @Perroloco for replying me soo fast =D and it work.

Answer (score 0):

**In kotlin You may use..**

```
radioAnswerGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->

//radioAnswerButton is your correct radio button id

val isChecked = radioAnswerButton.isChecked

  if (isChecked) {
      Log.e("is check","right answer--")
  }else{
      Log.e("is check","wrong answer")
  }

})
```